# How do I find the last occurrence of a match using regexp in MATLAB?

Tags: regex, matlab

If I have the following string in MATLAB:

```
str = '/* This is a comment */ int x; /* sectionEndExample */';
```

How do I find the comment that contains a given string. In this example, the string is 'sectionEndExample'.

```
expr = ['^.*/\*.*sectionEndExample.*\*/'];
sectionEndIdx1 = regexp(str, expr);
```

But this always returns the sectionEndIdx1 as 1 which means it's matching this first 
    '/*' 
whereas I want it to match the last 
    '/*'.

I am looking in the documentation and have so far played around with the lookAround options. However, I can't figure out a way to do it in MATLAB :(

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are asking completely but you can edit the `regexp` function to return exactly what matches in a cell array. and Then with this cell array, simply chose the last index of it, which will be the last match.

```
sectionEndIdx1 = regexp(str, expr,'match');
```

This will however, return the entire string you provided as a match, because based on the criteria you give your regular expression, it will match the entire string.

If this is not the desired result, you will need to modify your regular expression string.

I would suggest using a website like [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) to test regular expressions before plugging them into `MATLAB`.

Comment: @SwatiTiwari Besides, if you want to find a fixed string such as "/* sectionEndExample */" you don't need a regular expression. `strfind` will do.

Comment: +1 for the link to regexpal. Use `expr = '/\*.sectionEndExample.\*/'`

Comment: I figured out a way to do it. `expr = '/\*[^\*]*sectionEndExample[^\*]*\*/'`

Comment: @SwatiTiwari If the answer helped resolve your problem please rem to click on the check mark next to it...